# Is it possible to include groups in JWT token in case of implicit flow?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, swagger

Hi I am working on Azure AD and .net core application. I am trying to implement authentication and authorization. I have swagger configured with my .net core application. I am able to do authentication using swagger. Currently I have about 100 groups where I am part of.  I am using implicit grant flow for swagger authentication. As per documentations I have gone through,

If there are more than 5 groups then JWT token will include  "hasgroups": "true" and - In my case I am able to see "hasgroups": "true"  in JWT token.

If group is synchronized to Azure AD using Azure AD Connect, you can then display the group name - In my case synchronized to Azure AD using Azure AD Connect but I am not able to see ids nor names.

I have more than 100 groups so due to url restriction it is impossible to get groups when we are using implicit flow.

Also, If I have only back-end apis, In that case which authorization flow is recommended to use?  API will know nothing of the calling app.

In implicit flow there will be only call to azure ad to get Access token and In authorization grant flow there will be two calls one for to get authorization code and then using authorization code to get access token. This is my understanding. I am not sure If I understood this correctly or not.
Can someone help me to understand  above two points? I am having some confusion over the above two points. Any help would be appreciated in this regard. Thanks

Below is my swagger implementation.

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
                    TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl,
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"Read", "guid/.default" }
                    }
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                        { "oauth2", new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" } }
                });
            });
```

In Configure,

```
  app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {

                c.OAuthClientId(swaggerUIOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerUIOptions.ClientSecret);
                c.OAuthRealm(azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
                c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new { resource = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId });
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

If a user has too many groups, they won't be in the access token.
The limit is smaller for implicit flow since the token is returned in the URL.

In those cases your back-end needs to check group memberships via Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Hi Junnas. Thanks. Can I get any link to msdn for the above? Thanks

Comment: Limit is mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims. Get user's groups via Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Currently I dont get group ids or group names in my JWT token and I get "hasgroups": "true" in my JWT token. This means I have to use graph api to call group info. If it is synced then also i will not get group details. I get only "hasgroups": "true".

Comment: Also In the url you have shared they mentioned  200 groups for a JWT token. This is  using implicit flow or authorization flow? In implicit flow JWT token will be in url so JWT token can contain 200 tokens?

Comment: I updated my question just want to know If I have only back-end apis, In that case which authorization flow is recommended to use? Also with swagger can we use authorization flow instead of implicit flow?